# Adafruit Trinket M0 persistent storage?

Tags: attiny, adafruit, eeprom

I am using an Adafruit Trinket M0 to program a small game and would like to save the game state every so often. I am programming it through the Arduino IDE as the chip does not have enough space to run my game with circuitpython (too many libraries). Does the Trinket M0 have any form of persistent storage that I can use, or will I need to use a different device?

I couldn't find EEPROM in the documentation, but I wasn't able to find a definitive answer whether or not it has any form of long term storage. Knowing the board is based on the Attiny85 I would expect it to have 512 bytes or so, but the arduino library is giving me problems when I try to use it as well, so there is no way for me to trial and error this.

Comment: Add a i2c eeprom to store data. There is a 'emulation' eeprom that writes to flash memory. I don't know the current status of that library. I don't know if that works with the trinket and I don't know if that has been added to the arduino eeprom library. https://github.com/cmaglie/FlashStorage The adafruit trinket m0 is not based on a attiny chip. Please add this link to your question: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3500

Answer (score 1):

The M0 boards use a SAMD chip. It has no EEPROM. To store data without additional hardware like external EEPROM or SD card, you can use the flash memory of the SAMD. But it has a drawback of limited count of writes to flash memory.

An [EEPROM emulation library](https://github.com/cmaglie/FlashStorage) exits. It uses the flash memory, so the drawback of limited writes, applies. I used it, it works. The library is almost official. The author is Arduino's coworker.